# Using CSS Transition with Left Property Doesn't Transition Smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm building a sliding button feature in my website. Basically when I click on an icon, a rectangle slides over the icon. Here's what I'm doing.

**JS**

```
icon.addEventListener('click', () => { rectangle.classList.add('slideRight') })
```

**CSS**

```
.slideRight {
  left: 66%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

What happens is the rectangle moves to `left: 66%`, but it doesn't transition. It snaps to its position instantly. How do I make the rectangle transition for the 0.5s instead of snapping?

Comment: add a default value (left:0%)

Comment: I have an id for the rectangle called `#buttonBg`.  If I add `left: 0%` to that id, when I add the `.slideRight` class to it, the id overrides the class and it doesn't shift at all.

Comment: Actually, I changed it a little bit so it doesn't override now, and it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function () {
        console.log(document.getElementById("content").className);
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById("content").className = "content slide";
        }, 2000);
      };
```

```css
.wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        position: relative;
      }
      .content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        transition: left 0.5s;
        background-color: aqua;
      }
      .slide {
        left: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content" id="content"></div>
    </div>
```

First you need to give it an initial value like `left: 0`

```
.slideRight {
  left: 66%;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Same result as before

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't catch the transition because you didn't set the original left as '0px'.
So at first set the left property of rectangle as '0px' and change 'left:66%' as 'left:66% **!important**' so that as it actually works.

Comment: I heard !important is a bad practice. I just had to rearrange a little code and I don't need to use it. But setting left to 0 worked